# Поясните фрагмент кода

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте, обьясните на пальцах, что это значит:

```
int (*fp) (int a);
```

Что тут делается? Можно по подробнее? 
Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Переменная-указатель на функцию с именем fp. Функция принимает на вход параметр типа int и возвращает тоже int.

```
int foo(int a)
{
  return ++a;
}

.....
int (*fp)(int a);
fp = &foo;

fp(5); // вызов функции foo через указатель на неё.
```

Comment: А, если надо перегрузить функцию? Передаем в func 2-е переменные, то это будет выглядеть так:
int (*fp)(int a, int b);
?

Comment: Нет, если нужно в одном месте вызвать одну функцию, а в другому другую через один и тот же указатель.

Comment: @fogbit, при вызове fp() нужен параметр

Comment: Кстати, можно писать просто

fp = foo;